# Media not found message

Tags: hardware

When are you going to fix the media not found message when trying to mount a diskette. This problem has been going on far too long and i would have thought by now it would have been addressed as there are many complaints about it on different web sites.
Robert

Comment: Please be _specific_ about your problem. Asking when "we" (we are not Canonical employees, by the way — we are volunteers) are going to solve some unspecified and vague problem does not help and will not get you any answers. Describe your problem _precisely_, explain what you want, and ask how to go about it.

Comment: WOW You really know how to ask for help! Excellent question! I will end this with showing you the manual: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/fdmount.1.html Should have all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I am right in saying that this is something fixed in your motherboard boot menu.

There should be an option for allowing or disallowing disk drives etc. In there you should **disallow the floppy disk**.

I hope this helps - everyone!

Comment: you are mistaken. He is actually having trouble mounting drives and also having trouble figuring out that ASKUBUNTU is not actually canonical. And finally you also having trouble answering the problem(`disalow the floopy disk`??).

Comment: You could be right.

I assumed that he was getting a "media not found when trying to mount a diskette" message. As opposed to a "media not found".

The problem could still be in the BIOS configuration though.